# How to split a line in segments of a given length in cartodb?

Tags: carto

How can I split a (poly)line in segments of a given length in cartodb?

I want to be able to visualize segments of street, each 4m long, following the road curve.
One way would have been to trace the road side with a line and then cut it in chunks of 4m.

I cannot use a simple "grid", as the 4m have to be tangent to the path, and I did not find a way to create points or lines with a given distance of each other.

It seems possible in QGIS and OpenJump ([How to split a line every x meters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132880/how-to-split-a-line-every-x-meters)) but I cannot find a way to do it in cartodb.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

cartodb use postgres/postgis so you can make nice sql queries. I couldn't try but this one below should help:
[Split linestring to smaller lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48223/split-linestring-to-smaler-lines)